# Godot: Im setting a variable but its acting as a pointer

Tags: sqlite, godot, gdscript

var t = db.query_result

Then I use this in a for with multiple other queries which change the value of t, but I want to set it at the value of my first query? How do I set t at db.query_result and make it not change afterwards when I make other queries?

```
func setTuto1():#
db.open_db()
db.query("select ID from currentTutorialMap where LandTextureType = 'Stone0';")
var t = db.query_result
print(t)
print(t.size())
print(t[1]["ID"])
for i in range(0, t.size()):
    var x = rng.randi_range(0, 6)
    if x==0:
        db.query("update currentTutorialMap set LandTextureIndex = 10 where ID == %d;" % t[i]["ID"])
    elif (x==1 or x==2):
        db.query("update currentTutorialMap set LandTextureIndex = 9 where ID == %d;" % t[i]["ID"])
    elif (x==3 or x==4):
        db.query("update currentTutorialMap set LandTextureIndex = 11 where ID == %d;" % t[i]["ID"])
    elif (x==5 or x==6):
        db.query("update currentTutorialMap set LandTextureIndex = 12 where ID == %d;" % t[i]["ID"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `t` is local to your method (`func`). If you want it to keep its value, make it a field (declare it outside any `func`, the guidelines suggest to do that at the top of the script).

And if you just want the first result, and not overwrite it, you can have a `bool` variable, set to `false` by default. When you write `t`, you set it to `true`. That allows you to check if you have already set `t`.

Something like this:

```
var _is_t_set := false
var _t

func setTuto1():
    if _is_t_set:
        # we have been here before
        # do whatever you do in this case
        pass
    else:
        # first time we are here
        db.open_db()
        db.query("blah blah blah")
        _t = db.query_result
        _is_t_set = true # so we do not enter here again
```

---

Alternatively you could use null. Although double check if `db.query_result` can be null.

Something like this:

```
var _t = null

func setTuto1():
    if _t != null:
        # we have been here before
        # do whatever you do in this case
        pass
    else:
        # first time we are here
        db.open_db()
        db.query("blah blah blah")
        _t = db.query_result
```

---

And, by the way, [use prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68555236/402022).